# Error in Http test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, callout, code-coverage, httpcalloutmock

All I have written test class for my http future method I am receiving assertion error. Please look at my class & test class below.

```
public with sharing class contactAutoAddress {
private static boolean isTrigger = false;

public class contactException extends Exception {}

public static void onAfterInsert(List<Contact> triggerNew)
{  
    if(isTrigger == true)
    {
        return;
    }
    else{
        isTrigger = true;
        List<Id> contactsId = new List<Id>();

        for(Contact c : triggerNew)
            contactsId.add(c.Id);
        system.debug(LoggingLevel.Info, 'onAfterInsert called with '+triggerNew+'; sending IDs='+contactsId);
        makeUSPSCallout(contactsId);
    }
}

@future(callout = true)
public static void makeUSPSCallout(List<Id>cnt)
{
    string resp;
    List<Contact> contactsSet = [SELECT Id, MailingPostalCode, MailingCity, MailingState, MailingCountry FROM contact where id = :cnt];

    for(Contact c : contactsSet)
    {
        String ZipCode = c.MailingPostalCode;
        String userID = '************';
        String reqXML = '<CityStateLookupRequest USERID="'+userID+'"><ZipCode ID= "0"><Zip5>'+zipCode+'</Zip5></ZipCode></CityStateLookupRequest>';
        string endpoint ='http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll?API=CityStateLookup&XML=';
        endpoint = endpoint+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(reqXML,'UTF-8');
        system.debug(LoggingLevel.Info,'zipCode.cls: calling endpoint='+endpoint);
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');

        try {
            res = http.send(req);
            if (res.getStatusCode() != 200) {
                throw new contactException(res.getStatus());
            }
        } catch (contactException e) {
            system.debug(LoggingLevel.Error, 'Error HTTP response code = '+res.getStatusCode()+'; calling '+endpoint );
            return;
        }

        resp = res.getBody();
        system.debug('res :' + resp); 
        Dom.Document docx = new Dom.Document();
        docx.load(resp);
        system.debug('Docx' + docx);
        Dom.XmlNode xroot = docx.getRootElement();
        Dom.XmlNode zipNode = xroot.getChildElement('ZipCode',null),
            stateNode = zipNode == null? null: zipNode.getChildElement('State',null),
                cityNode = zipNode == null? null: zipNode.getChildElement('City',null);


        if(xroot.getChildElement('ZipCode',null)!= null){

            if(stateNode != null && stateNode.getText() != null){
                String state = xroot.getChildElement('ZipCode',null).getChildElement('State',null).getText();
                c.MailingState = state;
                system.debug('State'+ state);
            }
            if(cityNode != null && cityNode.getText() != null)
            {
                string city = xroot.getChildElement('ZipCode',null).getChildElement('City',null).getText();
                string titleCaseCity = properCase.toTitleCase(city);
                c.MailingCountry = 'US';
                c.MailingCity = titleCaseCity;
            }
        }

    }    
    update contactsSet;     
    isTrigger = false;  
}
```

}

My test class

```
@isTest(seealldata=true)
public class contactAutoAddressTest {
       static testmethod void testMe(){
        contact cnt = new contact(lastName = 'test', email='test@test.com');        
        cnt.MailingPostalCode = '12345';
        cnt.MailingState = 'IN';
        cnt.MailingCity = 'New York';
        cnt.MailingCountry= 'US';
        insert cnt;
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new mockAddress());
        contactAutoAddress.makeUSPSCallout(new List<Id> {cnt.Id} );
        HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
        String contentType = response.getHeader('Content-Type');
        System.assert(contentType == 'application/xml);
        String actualValue = response.getBody();
        String expectedValue = '{"foo":"bar"}';
        System.assertEquals(actualValue, expectedValue);
        System.assertEquals(200,response.getStatusCode());

    }

}
```

My mockup class

```
@istest
global class mockAddress implements HttpcalloutMock {
global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
 System.assertEquals('http://api.salesforce.com/foo/bar', req.getEndpoint());
        System.assertEquals('GET', req.getMethod());
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
        res.setBody('{"foo":"bar"}');
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        return res;
    }
}
```

I am getting following error.

> System.AssertException: Assertion Failed

Comment: I still don't have answer for this. @sfdcfox would you be able to help me with this? Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

Of course your content type is not yet set. Basically here's what you're doing:

```
HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
system.assertEquals('application/json', response.getHeader('Content-Type'));
```

You shouldn't really be testing the mock anyway, but rather how your code which performs the callout responds to it. That means you should query back for the `Contact` records and assert that they were updated as you expect.

One other thing, your callout appears to expect an XML response, but your mock response sends back JSON. You'll need to fix that to properly test your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58681/discussion-between-aman-and-adrian-larson).